# Phpstorm shows js files as updated

Tags: phpstorm

When doing "Sync with deployed on ..." in phpstorm, the diff shows as if all local js files were updated recently and thus offers to upload them even they were not changed or most recent changes are on the server. Anyone had this weird issue or knows how to fix it?

Comment: What OS are you using on the server, what OS locally? Have permissions changed recently on any of the systems?

Comment: Windows 8.1 locally, linux on the server. I don't think I ever chnaged permissions on windows in my life. On the server permissions haven't changed as far as I know. The most weird think id that it's .js files only...

Comment: No I think in the latest case it's all files and it's because they are checked out with git, so they all have more recent modifiy time...

Answer (score 0):

The GUI allows you to switch to "Compare by: Content". Note that this will be more bandwidth-intensive than comparing by modification date.

See e.g. this for a screenshot: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/comparing-deployed-files-and-folders-with-their-local-versions.html

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it takes ages to sync comparing content, so it's not an option.